# Validation Rule on Lead Status Prior To Conversion

Tags: validation-rule, leads, lead-conversion

Status should be "Sales Qualification" before it can be "Converted". Any other stages should fire an error. My validation rule code is:

```
AND(
NOT(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) = 'Sales Qualification'), 
TEXT(Status) = 'Converted'
)
```

It's not working. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you enable triggers and validation rules in Setup > Customize > Leads > Lead Settings?

Comment: Yes, all are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187194&type=1) for example 
Need to create a validation rule to prevent the lead conversion based on the value in the Lead Status field.
Resolution
To allow converting the leads only with Lead Status as "Qualified", please use the validation rule below:

```
AND( IsConverted, NOT( TEXT( PRIORVALUE(Status) )  = "Qualified") )
```

Note:

The above validation rule is considered on any field and (Isconverted) function is only on Lead object.